# Setting custom Bash completion causes hang on tab

Tags: bash, autocomplete, john-the-ripper

I have Bash completion for JTR setup as [recommended](https://countuponsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/jtr-cheat-sheet.pdf):

> Enable bash completion. add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` .
>
> `<JtR path>/run/john.bash_completion`

Therefore I have this in `.bashrc`:

```
. /mnt/data/Documents/Build/JohnTheRipper/run/john.bash_completion
```

This works fine, and I can Bash complete when calling the `john` binary.

However, I made a script called `johnit` so I can call John The Ripper with various modes, wordlists and rules in one shot.

As noted in the comments within `john.bash_completion` I used the following syntax to "copy" the bash completion rules to `johnit`:

```
complete -F _john johnit
```

`johnit` resides in `~/bin/johnit` and this is in the current user's `$PATH`.

However, when tab completing with `johnit` the shell hangs and never autocompletes.

As a test I tried this with another, empty, file, marked as executable:

```
touch magic 
chmod +x magic
```

And this appears to autocomplete but only without the leading dot and slash (`./magic`) so Bash wouldn't actually call it properly when executed:

```
magic --format=
```

What gives?